# How to hide all elements not containing a particular value of a data class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

Okay, bear with me. The (template) HTML in question is this:

```
<section class="page3 active" data-index="3">                   
<div class="plaque">
    <header class="title">Launch Count</header>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <span>Total</span>
        <ul>
            <li data-sheet="1">Total</li>
            <li data-sheet="2">Falcon 9</li>
            <li data-sheet="3">Falcon Heavy</li>
            <li data-sheet="4">Falcon 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="metric" data-sheet="1">12</td>
                <td class="metric" data-sheet="2">7</td>
                                    <td class="metric" data-sheet="3">7</td>
                                    <td class="metric" data-sheet="4">7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="unit" data-sheet="1">Launches</td>
                <td class="unit" data-sheet="2">Test</td>
                                    <td class="unit" data-sheet="2">Test</td>
                                    <td class="unit" data-sheet="4">Test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p data-sheet="1">A paragraph</p>
        <p data-sheet="2">Test</p>  
                    <p data-sheet="3">Test</p>
                    <p data-sheet="4">Test</p>          

    </footer>
</div>
</section>
```

See that `<div>` contaning a `<ul>`? There's already another jQuery script applied which turns that into a select style dropdown menu. Note they're tagged with a custom HTML5 data attribute.

What I want is a rule which **hides all** elements **within** section.active which **contain** a data-sheet attribute that is **not equal** to '1'.

I simply cannot build one myself, despite all my attempts. Help? I've already tried:

```
$('section.page3 *.data-sheet').not("[data-sheet*='1']").hide();
```

With no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('section.page3 [data-sheet]').not("[data-sheet*='1']").hide();
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/257Rq/)</kbd>

---

`$('section.page3 [data-sheet]')` select elements in `section` with class `page3` that have attribute `data-sheet`

`.not("[data-sheet*='1']")` select elements with `data-sheet` containing `1`

---

if you want to match `1` only

```
$('section.page3 [data-sheet]').not("[data-sheet='1']").hide();
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/257Rq/)</kbd>

Comment: I dont think he want `*=` because that will match a `data-sheet="10"`. He wants not equals to 1

Comment: @TusharGupta thank you very much for the explanation, looks like I was missing those square brackets!